# Spokes to DT Swiss cyclocross wheel

Tags: cyclocross, spokes, panniers

I have CSW MA 1.9 wheel on my cylcocross bike.
I already replaced few spokes in the rear wheel,
I plan to do a long trek in the coming spring with front and rear pannier (and my weight) and I want to get the strongest spokes that will fit to this specific model, How can I find out which spokes of DT Swiss would be eligible with my wheel?

Comment: If you're replacing spokes at an abnormal rate, you should consult someone to see if the wheel was built properly (and if not, rebuild it or get a new wheel) and if its appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I can't find a closeup of that particular wheel.  The only situation where you would need "special" spokes is if you have a wheel which uses spokes with no "hook" on the end.  But this is very rare.  Otherwise, spoke size is length, diameter, and "butted" or not.  DT makes pretty good spokes, but there are a few other manufacturers that custom wheel builders feel are better, for various reasons.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Product recommendations are [off topic](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. As such, I have removed that portion of your question so that it will not be closed by the community.

Comment: Note that DT Swiss uses some very special spokes in some of their more expenisve wheels... I once had to replace a spoke on a high-end DT Swiss wheel, requiring me to buy a complete spoke set of not less than *half a dozen* different spokes, all used in the wheel set I was riding.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already replacing spokes, the easiest way to find out is take a broken spoke from each side of the wheel and measure it. There are no hidden differences, you only need to match the length, thickness and type of spoke head. Note that spokes may be thinner at the center than ends, this is called butting.

Comment: And, curiously, "butted" spokes that are thinner in the middle are more durable in some situations.